# Regular Expression JavaScript detect comment

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect comment in a textarea

So, I want to detect  `//` OR `/* */`

I try to use that

```js
var commV = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value;
var commReg = commV.replace("//","<b>//</b>");
```

This code detect `//` and make them bold, but I want to detect the fallowing text and make them bold

And for that `/* */` I need to detect All between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the prototype match, it will return an array with all the bloc comments:

```
var blocComm = commV.match(/\/\*[\w\d\s]*\*\//g);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: This RegExp it's just for `/* */`, but that `//` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, I found the solution